# String to bytes and back not working

Tags: java

please help me to solve the issue

```
public class MasherExample {
        static class Masher {
        static String mash(String s) {
            byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
            byte[] mashed = new byte[bytes.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                mashed[i] = (byte) ~bytes[i];
            }
            return new String(mashed);
        }
        static String unmash(String s) {
            byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
            byte[] unmashed = new byte[bytes.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                /*
                unmashed[i] = (byte) ~bytes[i];
                */
            }
            return new String(unmashed);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testString = "1, 2, 3";
        if(Masher.unmash(Masher.mash(testString)).equals(testString)) {
            System.out.println("OK");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

string is not getting decoded to the original string, some issue with the `unmashed` function, please help me to solve the issue, thanks in advance....

Comment: What's the deal with commented `unmashed` negation?

Comment: Note that `String.getBytes()` uses the JVM's default charset. You might want to be explicit about the charset, in order to ensure that it behaves as expected however the JVM running it is configured.

Comment: it is well known riddle. do you want a solution from us?

Comment: @dit yes, can you please help me?

Comment: Works for me if I uncomment the negation, so the question fails to sufficiently describe the problem.

Comment: @Klas Lindbäck but for me it is not working, I had tried in both intellij and eclipse

Comment: Perhaps it depends on locale or java version?  I used Java 7 from the command line with swedish locale.

Comment: @Klas Lindbäck can u please share a screenshot, thanks.

Comment: @Klas Lindbäck see the code showing "Error" when I compailed online https://coderpad.io/9TE3GWJK

Comment: It is locale/encoding dependent. See Peter Lawreys answer for a working solution.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that not all bytes are valid characters in the encoding you are using. e.g. in UTF-8 characters with the high bit set form part of a multi-byte character and not all combinations are valid.

What you can do is use an encoding which doesn't do this.

```
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    byte[] mashed = new byte[bytes.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        mashed[i] = (byte) ~bytes[i];
    }
    return new String(mashed, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

Comment: I need to do it without specifying encoding

Comment: Shouldn't `new String(s.getBytes())` bring back `s` regardless of the encoding? Both ways it is the same (default) encoding?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic you are right, provided you don't change those bytes.

Comment: @sanoop in that case, you need to do an encoding of your own because not all byte values are a valid character using the default encoding.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic No. If any character in `s` contains a character which is not supported by the default encoding, then it'll be replaced. Try it with e.g. "€" and ISO-8859-1. This will result in "?".

Comment: @DraganBozanovic while the character ` ` should be supported, the byte which is `~' '` will not be supported.

Comment: But `~(~' ')` should be supported again? Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, I did not see that a new `String` is built from the changed bytes. I thought it is just moving bytes around before rebuilding the string again. Sorry, my fault.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Your code only works for the example string, not for all possible strings. Using a single-byte encoding doesn't help.

Comment: @xehpuk it works for all possible strings which use the supported range of characters from `(char) 0` to `(char) 255`. You are right that it won't work for any others.

Answer (score -1):

hi Sanoop when I ran your program in eclipse I found certain mistakes which I have corrected. Now your code prints "Ok" and not "Error". Here's the code below:

```
public class MasherExample {
        static class Masher {
        static String mash(String s) {
            byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
            byte[] mashed = new byte[bytes.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                mashed[i] = (byte) ~bytes[i];
            }
            return new String(mashed);
        }
        static String unmash(String s) {
            byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
            byte[] unmashed = new byte[bytes.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {

                unmashed[i] = (byte)~bytes[i];

            }
            return new String(unmashed);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testString = "1, 2, 3";
        if(Masher.unmash(Masher.mash(testString)).equals(testString)) {
            System.out.println("OK");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on which characters you use.  Try using all the characters from 0 to 255 for example.

Comment: I have just changed unmash fucntion little bit

Comment: This should still fail I don't see any change barring the fact that you un-commented already not working code.

Comment: @Praveen Jin sorry, it's not working.

Comment: what should be your output . I am getting "Ok" is it correct.

Comment: @Praveen Jin Did you check your code? Giving Error only

Comment: ya in eclipse it ran gave output as "Ok"

Comment: No it only give Error

Comment: CAn you try copying the code I have pasted into program and execute

Comment: Ya but giving Error. Can u post snapshot??